# Verifying integration by parts of an arbitrary function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Suppose that I have an arbitrary differentiable function $G$ which depends on $s$: $G(s)$.

Now suppose that I want to do the following integral: $$\int ds \;\; s \frac{\partial G(s)}{\partial s}.$$

However, I do not know the exact form of $G(s)$, so I cannot *do* the integral; I can only *"expand"* it.  One method to do this is integration by parts.  I *think* that integration allows me to rewrite the integral as $$\boxed{\int ds \;\; s \frac{\partial G(s)}{\partial s} = sG(s) - \int ds \, G(s)},$$

but I would like to verify this to make sure I am not making any mistakes.  **Is there any way that I can use Mathematica to verify that for the boxed equation, the left-hand side indeed equals the right-hand side?**

I have tried this:

```
Integrate[s*D[G[s], s], s] == s*G[s] - Integrate[G[s], s]
```

but Mathematica (I am running version 8) does not know how to automatically evaluate this.

Comment: My answer to this question also applies to yours: [Order of integration changes output of indefinite multiple integral in Mathematica 7](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/order-of-integration-changes-output-of-indefinite-multiple-integral-in-mathemati). Do a derivative on both sides of your equation, and the result is `True`. So I'd say this is a duplicate of the linked question.