# How to get the desired (equivalent) answer from Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is the integrand:

```
1/beta/(2*z)/(1 - beta) // TraditionalForm
```

Integrating with respect to `z`, gives

```
Integrate[1/beta/(2*z)/(1 - beta), z]
```

> -(Log[-2 (-1 + beta) beta z]/(2 (-1 + beta) beta))

What I hope to get is from doing so:

```
1/beta/2/(1 - beta)*Integrate[1/z, z]
```

> Log[z]/(2 (1 - beta) beta)

But if I look at the two answers, they are not equivalent, eg the difference does not simplify to 0.

Should I make some assumptions in the first case? Or Am I doing something wrong?

*Update*:

```
ans1 = Integrate[1/beta/(2*z)/(1 - beta), z]
ans2 = 1/beta/2/(1 - beta)*Integrate[1/z, z]
tmp = ans1 - ans2 // FullSimplify
```

I was thinking that `tmp` should be zero, but I was wrong. It is a constant, which is free of `z`.

So both answers are correct.

But could I get the desired answer in the first place anyway?

Comment: They're the same up to a constant offset. (Remember: `Log[ab] = Log[a] + Log[b]` for real positive numbers, and the indefinite is unique only up to a constant.)

Comment: @march Yes, I see what you meant!! But just for the sake of this question, could I get the desired answer?

Comment: Maybe if you tried to Simplify Assuming that z is positive and that beta is between 0 and 1? The problem is that MMA assumes numbers are complex by default. So I don't know.

Comment: Closely related: [Order of integration changes output of indefinite multiple integral in Mathematica 7](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17196/245)

Comment: @Jens Thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: Did the answers below answer your question completely? If so, please accept one! If not, please let us know what could be improved.

Answer (score 4):

The brute force method to arrive at your second solution

```
f[z_] = 1/beta/(2*z)/(1 - beta);

cl = CoefficientList[f[z], 1/z];

cl.Integrate[(1/z)^Range[0, Length[cl] - 1], z]
```

> Log[z]/(2*(1 - beta)*beta)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a definite integral:

```
Integrate[1/beta/(2*z0)/(1 - beta), {z0, 1, z}, Assumptions -> {z > 1, 0 < beta < 1}]
(* Log[z]/(2 beta - 2 beta^2) *)
```

Of course, this requires by-hand tuning of the lower limit, but if you want a certain form (i.e. a certain choice of offset), then that's required anyway.